# How to change username in navigation header using data from fragment?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to change navigation header when user is logged into application. When user is logged, username and picture should change. I was trying with id from shared preference and it works, but when i try to get data from local database it crashes.

Is it problem that im trying to get data from Login fragment? Or im trying to get data in wrong place?

Username and picture gets changed when i change it from MainActivity so I think that problem is in fragment Login.

The code works fine until i try to get data from local database:

```
mpet.project2018.air.database.entities.Korisnik korisnik =new SQLite().select().from(mpet.project2018.air.database.entities.Korisnik.class).where(Korisnik_Table.id_korisnika.is(Integer.parseInt(id))).querySingle();
String korime = korisnik.getKorisnicko_ime();
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), korime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Currently my code is inside onDataLoaded and I get NullPointer:
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String mpet.project2018.air.database.entities.Korisnik.getKorisnicko_ime()' on a null object reference

```
public class Login extends Fragment implements onLoginValidation, KorisnikDataLoadedListener, KarticaDataLoadedListener, LjubimacDataLoadedListener, SkeniranjeDataLoadedListener {

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public Login() {}
EditText edtUsername;
EditText edtPassword;
Button btnLogin;
Button btnPrijavaOdustani;

private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

private String globalId;

private ProgressDialog progress;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_login, container, false);
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction("Login");
    }

    checkConnection();

    edtUsername = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edtUsername);
    edtPassword = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnPrijavaOdustani = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnPrijavaOdustani);

    sharedPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); //u fragmentu dodaj this.getActivity..... jer nema CONTEXA
    if (sharedPreferences.getString("ulogiraniKorisnikId", "").toString().equals("ulogiraniKorisnikId")) { //getString
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, new HomeLoggedIn());
        ft.addToBackStack(null);

        ft.commit();
    }


    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String username = edtUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = edtPassword.getText().toString();
            //validate form
            if (validateLogin(username, password)) {
                //do login
                doLogin(username, password);
                showLoadingDialog();

            }

        }


    });

    btnPrijavaOdustani.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, new HomeLoggedOut());
            ft.addToBackStack(null);

            ft.commit();
            }
        }
    );

    return view;
}


protected boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
public void checkConnection(){
    if(!isOnline()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Nije uspostavljena internet veza", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
//LoadingDialog
  public void showLoadingDialog() {

    if (progress == null) {
        progress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progress.setMessage("Molimo pričekajte...");
        progress.setCancelable(false);
        progress.setButton("Odustani",(DialogInterface.OnClickListener)null);

    }
    progress.show();
}

public void dismissLoadingDialog() {

    if (progress != null && progress.isShowing()) {
        progress.dismiss();
    }
}


/**/
private boolean validateLogin (String username, String password){
    if (username == null || username.trim().length() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Potrebno je unijeti korisničko ime...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
    if (password == null || password.trim().length() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Potrebno je unijeti lozinku...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private void doLogin ( final String username, final String password){
    String username1 = edtUsername.getText().toString();
    String password1 = edtPassword.getText().toString();

    PrijavaMethod postMetodaZaPrijavu = new PrijavaMethod(this);

    String id = "";

    String response = "";

    postMetodaZaPrijavu.Upload(username1, password1);
}

@Override
public void onDataLoaded (String id){

    globalId=id;

    if (Integer.parseInt(id) != 0) {


        getActivity().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit()
                .putString(Config.ID_SHARED_PREF,id)
                .apply();

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Vas id je"+id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        downloadDatabase(id);

        /*zamjena izbornika*/
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.getMenu().clear();
        navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_main_drawer);

        navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        navigationView.removeHeaderView(navigationView.getHeaderView(0));
        navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header);




        mpet.project2018.air.database.entities.Korisnik korisnik =new SQLite()
                .select()
                .from(mpet.project2018.air.database.entities.Korisnik.class)
                .where(Korisnik_Table.id_korisnika.is(Integer.parseInt(id)))
                .querySingle();

        String korime = korisnik.getKorisnicko_ime();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), korime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        /**/
        clearBackStack();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, new HomeLoggedIn());
        //ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
        dismissLoadingDialog();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Korisnicko ime ili lozinka su netocni", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        dismissLoadingDialog();
    }


}

private void clearBackStack() {
    FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (manager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        FragmentManager.BackStackEntry first = manager.getBackStackEntryAt(0);
        manager.popBackStack(first.getId(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }
}

private void downloadDatabase(String id){
    KorisnikDataLoader kor=new KorisnikDataLoader(this);
    kor.loadUsersByUserId(id);
    //nastavak skidanja baze u loaderima zbog zavisnosti
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

@Override
public void KarticaOnDataLoaded(List<Kartica> listaKartica) {
    LjubimacDataLoader ljub=new LjubimacDataLoader(this);
    ljub.loadDataByUserId(globalId);
}

@Override
public void KorisnikOnDataLoaded(List<Korisnik> listaKorisnika) {
    KarticaDataLoader kar=new KarticaDataLoader(this);
    kar.loadDataByuserId(globalId);
}

@Override
public void LjubimacOnDataLoaded(List<Ljubimac> listaLjubimaca) {
    SkeniranjeDataLoader sken=new SkeniranjeDataLoader(this);
    sken.loadDataByUserId(globalId);
}

@Override
public void SkeniranjeOnDataLoaded(List<Skeniranje> listaSkeniranja) {
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    void onFragmentInteraction(String title);
}
private class ArticleFragment {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create **public** void changePicture() method in MainActivity and do your operations of setting image and text into navHeader in that method.

After that from fragment do the following to run that method of MainActivity:

```
((MainActivity)context).changePicture();
```

where

```
context = getContext();
```

Pass the required parameters in the function you need as per your requirements e.g imageUri / imageBitmap / textViews / imageViews.

**Note:** Method should be **public** so that you can call that from fragment.

Comment: Thank you, i created changePicture() method and it works in MainActivity, but it doesnt work in fragment Login.

Comment: Follow that way I suggested I tested that this will work... Replace ((MainActivity)getActivity).changePicture();   with ((MainActivity)context).changePicture();

Comment: I edited the answer apply this change. Mark this as an answer if this works bro :)

Comment: I get again nullpointer, 
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void mpet.project2018.air.mpet.MainActivity.changePicture()' on a null object reference

Comment: I added method here: 
     @Override
    public void LjubimacOnDataLoaded(List<Ljubimac> listaLjubimaca) {
        SkeniranjeDataLoader sken=new SkeniranjeDataLoader(this);
        sken.loadDataByUserId(globalId);


        ((MainActivity)getContext()).changePicture(); }  

I tested it and in this method i can get data from local database, but i think that problem is id of user since in this method id from user is globalId.

Comment: Buddy you need to debug that step by step in that case :/ Hope you will find the glith soon. Best of luck !

Comment: I tried refreshing the drawer and it didnt work. I have to use interface to make it work.